# New Venezuelan crypt worth it?

Tags: altcoin

Venezuela is about to launch its own [Petro cryptocurrency](http://www.elpetro.gob.ve/index-en.html)

Could the chaotic economic scenario the country have lived be a good chance to  change the usual  currency to a criptocurrency?

I mean, What can significantly mean success or failure in this case?

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, any chaos in the monetary system may be an opportunity for an alternative system.

Taking control out of the banks would be the first step towards an attempt to improve the economy, but we must be very careful about the government control.

The current scenario in Venezuela is all fault of the Government and not totally of the banks, if the government itself wants to launch a monetary system without the interventions of the banks what would be the logic of this?

Comment: It seems that the international (led by US) hostility, sanctions, and support of opposition activities definitely didn't help. Though of course the government didn't do a good job as well. Still, it would be a bit absolute to say it is "all fault of the government"?